How to read large CSV file and transform it to JSON file in GCP F4 instance class
I am using F4 instance machine and need to download 650Mb of CSV data from a gcloud storage and convert it to JSON file, which is larger size. When I tried doing it on F4 instance with 8 workers configured for Gunicorn, it returns an error below.

While handling this request, the process that handled this request was found to be using too much memory and was terminated. This is likely to cause a new process to be used for the next request to your application. If you see this message frequently, you may have a memory leak in your application or may be using an instance with insufficient memory. Consider setting a larger instance class in app.yaml.

I can't increase the instance to F4_1G glass, was looking into google resumable media but not able to get good documentation that I'm expecting.

The F4 only has 512 MB of memory. Temporary storage space consumes RAM. The F4 instance is too small to download a 650 MB file from Cloud Storage. F4+1G has enough memory to download the file, but not enough space to hold the results. There are tricks that you might be able to do, such as read parts of the file, process that part, and write the results to Cloud Storage, but that will require writing your own code to do that. You will quickly find that will be complicated to accomplish.

Gunicorn is not part of your problem, the error is caused by running out of memory. Configuring 8 workers configured for Gunicorn does not help you. No configuration of Gunicorn will solve the problem.
